# SQL Server: Usage for Double Colons in Column Name

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm working through a third party SQL Server 2008 database that I need to integrate into our own systems. A lot of the table column names use the following syntax:

> [cl::id]

or

> [cl::name]

I'm just intrigued as to what this is about. I've Googled it and not got anything other than something to do with schemas and permissions which I don't think applies in this case.

All I thought was it was just the developer's nomenclature.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's just the developer's nomenclature. [Delimited identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) mean you can use whatever characters you want in an object name, although it's often considered better to avoid them and use regular identifiers only, because it avoids a whole class of problems with needing to quote names in every script and piece of code that references them.

Comment: @Pondlife Thanks for ya comment. I thought it was a pretty naff way to name things!

Comment: I have come across the exact same thing, and I have determined that this is a side-effect of how the data was extracted. Rather than including certain "join" or "junction" tables in the data extract, the main data tables were "de-normalized" to include the junction table data. The name of the missing table was then pre-pended to column name in the new "de-normalized" table, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Delimited identifiers may contain special characters.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).  The colons have no special meaning.